Blazor - using SingalR hub to force refresh all user tabs logs multiple TaskCanceledException (RefreshFailed and CircuitUnhandledException)
I am using SignalR hub to refresh all tabs currently opened by specified user (e.g. after permission change). Hub connection is initialized in the MainLayout component.
public HubConnection HubConnection { get; set; }
private static Func<Task> callDisposeHubConnectionAsync;
private bool _isDisposed;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await InitHub();
        callDisposeHubConnectionAsync = DisposeHubConnectionAsync;
    }

    private async Task InitHub()
    {
        HubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri($"{HubConstants.Connection.Route}"), opts =>
            {
                opts.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            })
            .Build();

        HubConnection.On($"{HubConstants.Connection.ForcePageRefresh}", async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message received - ForcePageRefresh: {HubConnection.ConnectionId}");
            //await DisposeHubConnectionAsync();
            _navigationManager.Refresh();
        });

        HubConnection.On($"{HubConstants.Connection.Disconnect}", async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message received - Disconnect: {HubConnection.ConnectionId}");
            await DisconnectAsyncFromHubConnection();
        });

        await HubConnection.StartAsync();

        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.addEventListener", "beforeunload", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));

        Console.WriteLine($"Connection - started: {HubConnection.ConnectionId} ({DateTime.Now})");
    }

MainLayout component implements IAsyncDisposable
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeHubConnectionAsync();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public async Task DisposeHubConnectionAsync()
    {
        if(HubConnection != null && !_isDisposed)
        {
            var id = HubConnection.ConnectionId;
            Console.WriteLine($"Connection - closing...: {id}");

            try
            {
                await HubConnection.StopAsync();
                await HubConnection.DisposeAsync();
                _isDisposed = true;
                Console.WriteLine($"Connection - closed: {id} ({DateTime.Now})");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

When I have 3 tabs opened I am receiving message to take action in more than 3 hub connections (4,5 ... 8 etc. - it depends on how many times I refreshed all tabs/sessions before sending message to the hub).
DisposeAsync() method is not called immediately after the page is closed or refreshed - it takes about 3 minutes to get a log in the output with information that the hub connection is closed.
My app is not crashing anyway, tabs are refreshing correctly but I am getting multiple errors in my logs/output. Do you have any suggestions how to manage these errors, avoid them or just ignore?
I need only one hub connection for a each tab/session. When the page is closed or refreshed I want to close / dispose unnecessary connections. How to achieve that?
OUTPUT LOG:

2024-08-21T08:31:21.4910599+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager]   [RefreshFailed] Failed
to refreshSystem.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was
canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
2024-08-21T08:31:21.4913339+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager]   [RefreshFailed] Failed
to refreshSystem.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was
canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
2024-08-21T08:31:21.4916513+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager]   [RefreshFailed] Failed
to refreshSystem.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was
canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
2024-08-21T08:31:21.4917755+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost]   [CircuitUnhandledException] Unhandled
exception in circuit
'Jy_Vk4kXbB_5BNnlB3vjcE_IjYyd9hwBHrTJjSZ-GYY'.System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
A task was canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
2024-08-21T08:31:21.4919112+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost]   [CircuitUnhandledException] Unhandled
exception in circuit
'1Tkms7B8ImnvfBz46J8g8eC1mSRYYhBqpg7ekkqVW6M'.System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
A task was canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
2024-08-21T08:31:21.4932280+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager]   [RefreshFailed] Failed
to refreshSystem.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was
canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
2024-08-21T08:31:21.4937636+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost]   [CircuitUnhandledException] Unhandled
exception in circuit
'T5PzUx1qUgkhZLT-u-BQqEBfuYX8aDfUWPvh-og7ZHk'.System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
A task was canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
2024-08-21T08:31:21.4949202+02:00 FAIL    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost]   [CircuitUnhandledException] Unhandled
exception in circuit
'spD_gRuMVnJ1O6F0Q_qk9osI-Orce3cP0_4Ucksbt5U'.System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
A task was canceled.    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime
jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<g__RefreshAsync|0>d.MoveNext()

EDIT 1
Alternatively I can run DisposeHubConnectionAsync() with JS interop but it has to be done with static method so I need a way to pass current hub connection to JS script. Method below is not working correctly - only affects the last tab opened / refreshed.
Console OUTPUT:

Connection - started: CnofVIWtUEacIv2sElc91Q (22.08.2024 10:02:56
Connection - started: J4ZMmdAjFZwyGU1WwtgavQ (22.08.2024 10:03:08)
Connection - started: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g (22.08.2024 10:03:17)
Message received - ForcePageRefresh: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g
Message received - ForcePageRefresh: J4ZMmdAjFZwyGU1WwtgavQ
Message received - ForcePageRefresh: CnofVIWtUEacIv2sElc91Q
Connection - closing...: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g
Connection - closing...: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g
Connection - closing...: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g
Connection - closed: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g (22.08.2024 10:03:31)
Connection - closed: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g (22.08.2024 10:03:31)
Connection - closed: 5AKa6ErEm8y7DrPFL4e__g (22.08.2024 10:03:31)
Connection - started: PT6E8x14To_9wdC6Sw6wcw (22.08.2024 10:03:32)
Connection - started: RTMhEF8F2JzznVdheKYL1g (22.08.2024 10:03:32)
Connection - started: nzjfnGvhW2M8svjlMg1a3w (22.08.2024 10:03:32)
Connection - closing...: J4ZMmdAjFZwyGU1WwtgavQ
Connection - closed: J4ZMmdAjFZwyGU1WwtgavQ (22.08.2024 10:06:31)
Connection - closing...: CnofVIWtUEacIv2sElc91Q
Connection - closed: CnofVIWtUEacIv2sElc91Q (22.08.2024 10:06:31)

[JSInvokable]
public static async Task JSDisposeHubConnectionAsync()
{
    await callDisposeHubConnectionAsync.Invoke();
}
    

how to pass hub connection from MainLayout inside this JS function?
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('assemblyName', 'JSDisposeHubConnectionAsync');
});


Looks like you're using JSRuntime which has a cancellation token by default.

@GHDevOps - I have added more informations about DisposeAsync()

Why are you using JSInterop for your hubs? Why not use Blazor?

generally I want to close hub connection when tab is closed or refreshed, I can do it using Blazor but it does not work for me when page is refreshed / closed manually. the DisposeAsync() method is called with 3 minutes of delay - when signalR circuit is closed / disposed after reconnect failure so I search for workaround to close signalr hub connection when page is unloaded. I read somewhere that I can do it with JS interop but I need a way how to pass current hub connection into JS function
